# How to avoid a specific character in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table, with genetic information (name of the gene, function, strand...)
I want to retrieve the amount of chromosomes (21 as I'm working with the human genome). Problem is that some chromosomes are "repeated". For example:
`SELECT DISTINCT chrom FROM table LIMIT 6;`

```
chr1
chr10
chr10_GL383545v1_alt
chr10_GL383546v1_alt
chr11
chr11_JH159136v1_alt
```

As you can see I have more than one chr10, so if I count the `DISTINCT` chromosomes I get about 6000.

I've tried using `NOT LIKE "_"` but didn't work. I've thought I could "force" the result with `LIKE "chr1"` and so on, but I feel like cheating and is not exactly what I'm searching for. I would like a way to avoid every "_", but running
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT chrom) NOT LIKE "_" FROM table;` gives me back just 1 result...

`LEFT` is not optimal either, because I would have to specify the length of the string, and, I want a system that I could use without knowing anything about the expected result. So running a `LEFT "", 4` and `LEFT "", 5` is not what I'm searching for.
Is there a way I can count everything that does NOT CONTAIN a certain character? There's a better strategy?

Thank you very much!

Comment: your question is not clear  ..  try add  a clear data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: In a `NOT LIKE` you have to use `%` wildcards. Like this: `NOT LIKE "%\_%"`. See: [12.5.1 String Comparison Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscore is a wildcard character itself, so it must be escaped. Furthermore you want to match any characters before and after that underscore character so the `%` wildcard is needed around the escaped underscore.

```
SELECT count(chrom) FROM table WHERE chrom NOT LIKE '%\_%`;
```

Also you could use `substring_index()` to get distinct string before the underscore and count those:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(chrom, '_', 1)) FROM table;
```

Although that is almost definitely going to be slower.

Comment: Nice, it worked! Good point about counting before specifying "not to count", that was giving me a headache. Thank you for the clear explanation too!
Just for the record there's something weird as the first code line you give, returns me 26 chromosomes (22 + X + Y + M + Un), but the second line returns 25 (same as above but without Un). So there's some difference between your two solutions, although both work just fine. I'm using the refGene human annotation if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP` if you wish to keep it simple.`LIKE` is faster though.

```
SELECT count(chrom) FROM table WHERE chrom NOT REGEXP '_';
```

I also recommend `INSTR` which I think will perform better than `REGEXP`.

```
SELECT count(chrom) FROM table WHERE INSTR(chrom, '_')=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT chrom) NOT LIKE "_" FROM table;` is the location of the comparison and the lack of the `%` wildcards in the `LIKE` comparison string.

Either of the following should work for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT chrom) FROM table WHERE chrom  NOT LIKE '%|_%' ESCAPE '|';
```

Using `ESACPE`  and specifying an escape character after the `LIKE` is easier than using `\` in many cases since, depending on your scenario, you may need to remember to double escape with `\`. (or if you are writing this in say php, triple escape)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT chrom) FROM table WHERE LOCATE('_', chrom) > 0;
```

`LOCATE()` is also easier to use here. But I believe it would be slower than just doing a `LIKE`. The performance difference is probably pretty insignificant, so in most cases, its just preference.

Comment: Thank you, your first line gave the answer just as @JNevill 's code. It seems "\" does not need to be delcared with `ESCAPE`, found it interesting.

Comment: `\` is a character that is used for escaping by default. `ESCAPE` only needs to be used if you wish to use a character other than `\` for escaping. This is useful in scenarios, like using a `LIKE` from php, where you would otherwise need to double or triple escape if you were to use `\`